# How do you add 'cascade on delete' to sqlite code?

Tags: sqlite

I have tried looking around in sqlite studio and db browser, but I dont see anywhere that you can add this line of code for the foreign key fields in the database.

screenshot of what I see in db browser:
the line of code is missing. i cant edit the code from here, I dont know how to add the line in the program. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMEH6.png)

Comment: Please show the relevant code to get a faster answer.

Comment: I can't add code to the database, I can only view it.